# Removing signatures as legitimate edit reason

Tags: discussion

[My edit removing a signature got rejected as unhelpful](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15557862). Is removing the signature off of a post not a legitimate reason to edit? [StackExchange is explicitly against signatures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5029/229097), so I thought I was helping to maintain community standards.

Here is a photo of the edit below for those who don't have enough rep:
[image: rejected_edit]

Comment: [Relevant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2956).

Comment: @PaulCrovella that's fair. I'll work on getting to 2k and until then, hold off on the minor things more.